# Simulate keyboard input of ASCII characters

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard, ascii

I'm writing a WPF program to simulate keyboard input.

Everything works great, I could simulate almost everything things including `Alt + Tab` and `Alt + Tab`, but I failed to simulate input ASCII characters. For example: `Alt(down) + Number Pad 1` gives `☺` but my program gives nothing.

I've tried almost all different approaches I could find online, including
[InputSimulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32861108/probelm-while-using-inputsimulator), [keybd_event](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7305/Keyboard-Events-Simulation-using-keybd-event-funct), [SendKeys and PostMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047375/simulating-key-press-c-sharp), but all those failed.

I'm using a laptop with an external keyboard. I found when I pressed `Alt (on laptop) + Number Pad 1 (on external keyboard)`, it also failed to print `☺`. I have a strong feeling that this could be the reason why simulation failed (`Alt` keys on external keyboard, laptop and simulation are different).

So, my questions:

1. Does anyone have any solutions?
2. Is there a way to simulate a specific keyboard input?

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: @Ankit I'm using `InputSimulator` right now, my code is on my previous question, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32861108/probelm-while-using-inputsimulator).